# is the function $x(t)=t\cdot| t| \cos(t)$ differentiable in (-infinite,infinite)? Can you give me a proof?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

is the function $x(t)=t\cdot| t| \cos(t)$  differentiable in $(-\infty,\infty)$? Can you give me a proof?
I have to show that it's a solution of a continuous differential equation $f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$.

Comment: As the three factors are differentiable everywhere except in $0$, that's the only point you have to check.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

You only have to prove that $=t\cdot|t|=\begin{cases}t^2&\text{if }t>0, \\-t^2&\text{if }t<0, \\0&\text{if }t=0,
\end{cases}\:$ is differentiable, including at $0$.

Comment: It's my function of class 1(differentibly with continuous derivative)??

Comment: Well, you have to check whether $t\cdot|t|$ is $\mathcal C^1$, since $\cos t$ is $\mathcal C^\infty$. There could be a problem only at $0$.